# Check Overlap in a List

Tags: python

```
List = [[10,17],[13,15],[13,17]]

for x in list:
    x_list = x_list + [x[0]]
    y_list = y_list + [x[1]]
```

**Result:**

```py
x_list = [10, 13, 13]
y_list = [17, 15, 17]
```

This is what I did to separate the values. How do I check if there is an overlap in `x_list` or `y_list`?

Comment: What do you mean by overlap?

Comment: Overlap means to check if a one list has a same value for example, x_list has 13 and y_list has 17

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: the expexted output is x_overlap = 13 and y_overlap = 17 becuse there are more than one 13 in x_list and more than one 17 in y_list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count duplicates (i.e overlaps) as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

List = [[10,17],[13,15],[13,17]]

x_list, y_list = list(zip(*List))

overlaps_x = [e for e, c in Counter(x_list).items() if c > 1]
overlaps_y = [e for e, c in Counter(y_list).items() if c > 1]

print(overlaps_x)
print(overlaps_y)
```

**Output**

```
[13]
[17]
```

The idea is to first count the items and then output those elements with count greater than 1.